# Why do these variables in p5.js Javascript only work if defined inside the function?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am working with p5.js. I'm creating a class that's supposed to create buttons and make them interactive. It works perfectly if I define the variables for the buttons, such as length and width inside the functions (inside the class), but not if I do so inside the class but outside the function. I need to use these same variables in a few functions, so it'd be really helpful if I could have them work for all inside the class.

```js
class Buttons {
  constructor() {
    this.rectOver = false;
    this.x1 = 189;
    this.y1 = 189;
    this.textspacingx = 14;
    this.textspacingy = 22;
    this.buttonlength = 50;
  }
  
  table() {
    strokeWeight(0.5);
    fill(255);
    stroke(0);
    rect(120, 130, 230, 160);
  }
  
  range() {
    text("Low", 145, 210 );
    text("Mid", 145, 245 );
    text("High", 145, 280 );
    push();
    let angle2 = radians(270);
    translate(140, 260);
    rotate(angle2);
    let nuclear;
    nuclear = createFont("Avenir-Light", 20);
    textFont(nuclear, 20);
    fill(0);
    textAlign(LEFT);
    text("Climate", 0, 0);
    pop();
    text("Low", 195, 185 );
    text("Mid", 250, 185 );
    text("High", 305, 185 );
    text("Nuclear", 230, 155 );
  }
  
  display() {
    this.updateAA(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (this.rectOver) {
      fill(200);
    } else {
      fill(220);
    }
    stroke(200);
    rect(189, 189, 50, 25, 2);
    fill(0);
  }

  updateAA(x, y) {
    if (this.overRectAA(this.x1, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      this.rectOver = true;
    } else {
      this.rectOver = false;
    }
  }
  
  overRectAA(x, y, width, height) {
    if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width &&
        mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+height) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  mouseClicked() {
    if (this.overRectAA(this.x1, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      scenarioA.scenarioAA();
    } 
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  buttonAA = new Buttons();
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  buttonAA.table();
  buttonAA.display();
  buttonAA.range();
  buttonAA.mouseClicked();
}
```

Comment: I cannot run your code. gives an error: `[sketch.js, line 27] "createFont" is not defined in the current scope. If you have defined it in your code, you should check its scope, spelling, and letter-casing (JavaScript is case-sensitive).`   it looks like you are using a function `createFont` that is not defined

Comment: To make a runnable demo, try 'nuclear = new p5.Font("Avenir-Light", 20);' in lieu of 'createFont()'.  All the buttons created by your class will have a length of 50 (hard-coded to do this). The constructor needs to keep its variables if that's what you are asking, but parameters could be added to make it so they can be changed from one button to the next, eg 'myBtn = new Buttons(x,y,w);'